# Data vencimento MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, data

Tenho um cadastro onde armazeno a data de cadastro dos produtos. Porém preciso excluir esses produtos depois de 5 dias cadastrados no banco de dados. Tentei usar o `PHP` com o seguinte código:

```
$dataExcluir = mktime(null,null,null,date('m'),date('d') + 5,date('Y'),null);

while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){   
    $data = date($jm->DataCadastro,$dataExcluir);
    echo $data."<br>";     
}
```

Porém não funciona, ou seja, não é adiantado os 5 dias, mas se coloco no próprio PHP:

```
date('Y-m-d',$dataExcluir);
```

Alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: Para discutir assuntos relacionado ao site visite o [meta]. Sobre o assunto remover saudações, pode ir direto para esse link e ver que foi a decisão da maioria: [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/846/3117). Você pode dar sua opinião lá sobre o por quê que acha que as saudações devem ser mantidas e ouvir o que a comunidade tem a dizer. PS: não estou sendo sarcástico, você pode mesmo dar sua opinião.

Comment: Certo Math. Não sou contra a correção de palavras, códigos, etc, mas acho que uma saudação e agradecimento deveria ter. Acessarei o link e darei minha opinião. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode efetuar operações à uma data usando a combinação de funções [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) com [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) que converte a data para um número, depois você pode adicionar/subtrair elas com os modificadores de dia, mês, ano etc.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2015-05-01 + 5days'));
```

Uma opção é usar as classes [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) e [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). O método [add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) espera um objeto DateInterval que em seu construtor tem as informações do que será adicionado, no caso `P5D` é um período de 5 dias.

```
$dataVencimento = new DateTime('2015-05-01');
$dataVencimento->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
echo $dataVencimento->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Exemplo -ideon](http://ideone.com/0sHIIu)

Comment: Perfeito rray. Funcionou!!... Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), o primeiro argumento da função date() é o formato com o qual você quer exibir a data, e não tem nada a ver com fazer aritmética de datas. Datas e horas no PHP (assim como na biblioteca C do Unix) são inteiros, contando o número de segundos desde 1º de janeiro de 1970; você quer algo tipo

```
while ($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) {   
    $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($jm->DataCadastro) + 5 * 86400);
    echo $data."<br>";     
}
```

(Talvez você queira colocar uma constante `SEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA = 86400;` em alguma parte do seu código.)

Comment: Entendi. a variável $jm->DataCadastro está vindo no formato DATE() do mysql e quando coloquei seu código, está me retornando: 1970-01-05.

Comment: Você tem como imprimir o `$jm->DataCadastro`? Ele parece estar vindo em formato de string; a [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) deve fazer o serviço de converter a string para um inteiro.

Comment: $jm->DataCadastro retorna 2015-06-02. Está vindo do banco de dados date()